# Filtering to avoid the Slutsky-Yule effect in a moving window average?

Tags: r, time-series

Can anyone suggest a generally accepted method of filtering time series data to avoid the appearance of artifactual oscillations when smoothing the data using a moving window average?  Is it simply a matter of removing outliers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an appropriate ARIMA model all of which are simply weighted averages of the past. Outliers/Level Shifts/Local Time trends/Seasonal Pulses and Regular Pulses always need to be treated in conjunction with the ARIMA model. In this way you won't fall prey to the Slutzky Effect as your model will be parsimonious and reflective of the auto-correlative structure in the observed data.

Comment: Thanks.  That sounds like a good approach.  What I would actually like to do is slightly more complicated.  I have time series of both a dependent and an independent variable and I would like to examine changes in their correlation over time.  Based on your advice above, I'm guessing that an ARIMAX model might be the right approach.  What do you think?

Comment: Yes BUT if the correlative structure changes over time the break point can be found by applying the CHOW test which tests the constancy of parameters over time. This gets kind of tricky ( read you need good software ! ) to handle when you have data with anomalies such as pulses/level shifts.local time trends and/or seasonal pulses. If you post your data I will run my favorite software package and report the results to the list. If you don't want to post your data then all I can suggest is that you contact me off line and get your wallet out.